# Meteor aggregation TypeError: cannot read property

Tags: mongodb, meteor, publish, aggregation

I have a publish function which does an aggregation which I am converting from an array to a collection:

```
Meteor.publish("Jobsnohelpers", function (args) {
    var sub = this;

    var pipeline = [
         { $lookup:
         {
            from: "Helperjobs",
            localField: "job",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "temp"
        }},
           { 
               $match: 
               {"temp.Helpername": {$exists: false }}

           },

    Jobs.aggregate(
        pipeline,
        Meteor.bindEnvironment(
            function(err, result) {
            _.each(result, function(e) {
                    sub.added("Jobsnohelpers", Random.id(), 
                    {
                        ShortDesc: e._id,
                        LongDesc: "Hello this is a test",
                        LongDesc: e.LongDesc

                    }
                    );
                });
               sub.ready();
            },
            function(error) {
                Meteor._debug( "Error doing aggregation: " + error);
            }
        )
    );
});
```

When I run it. I get

Error doing aggregation: TypeError: Cannot read property '_id' of null

Also, I am developing on AWS Cloud 9. I wonder if that is creating an issue?

Comment: Which line of the file does the error come fomr

Comment: the error is coming from: ShortDesc: e._id,

Comment: @user8578092 which package are u using for aggregate also you should check for the error before working with the result.

Comment: meteorhacks:aggregate 1.3.0. Thanks for the error heads up.

Answer (score 1):

Meteor aggregation changed in a recent update in 1.7.1 The mongo aggregate function returns a different value now. It used to return a cursor now it returns a promise if I recall correctly.

The fix is to add .toArray() to the end of the original aggregate call and the behaviour is as it was before.

Mongo added this breaking change not meteor.

Answer (score 0):

This could be related to the fact that meteorhacks version of aggregate isn't supported by Meteor 1.7. Try this fork thats been modified to work with it: https://github.com/sakulstra/meteor-aggregate

For more details: https://github.com/meteorhacks/meteor-aggregate/issues/47

Answer (score 0):

I ended up scrapping aggregation and instead restructured the DB. I am not sure exactly what was going on with the event variable coming up null. Instead of using a mapping table I used subdocuments to model the one to many relationship. Ultimately, after experiencing a lot of frustration with Meteor aggregation, I think this is the right approach since it conforms with the conceptual model of Object Oriented databases.